# Is there any way to install a latex editor (for example Texmaker) to a chromebook?

Tags: latex, chrome-book

I would like to work with LaTeX in my chromebook, but I'd like to use a normal program instead of an online editor.

Comment: Here is a solution that works natively without installing Ubuntu via crouton: https://github.com/macbuse/Chromebook/blob/master/LaTeX.md

Comment: @GregMcshane Thank you. I don't have a Chromebook now, but It could be useful later. Why don't you add that link as an answer instead of a comment?